# I installed Ubuntu on my laptop but why can't I get any sound?

Tags: sound

After installing Ubuntu I can't get any sound out of my laptop unless I plug it into my monitor via HDMI. However, out of the speakers on the laptop there is nothing.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's most likely due to which sound device is selected for play through.

Left click on the speaker at the top right of the screen (assuming unity desktop) and you'll find ***Sound Settings...*** Click that.

[image]

After clicking on ***Sound Settings...*** the following screen will load:

[image]

Notice **Play sound through** on the left side of the **Output** Tab. Based on your explanation you'll likely find that an HDMI device is selected. Select the device you'd like to hear sound through and test the sound to verify it works.

Comment: You indirectly solved my problem! I was searching around about how to find sound settings and then I discovered I was missing a bunch of packages or dependencies! once I reinstalled desktop! THANK YOU SOSOSOSOSOSOSOSO MUCH!